# Run a program using cblas

Tags: c, compilation, blas

I need to start a program with using `cblas.h` library. I download `cblas.tgz` and decompile it, I Run the command:

```
ln -s Makefile.LINUX Makefile.in
```

and try to run my program.

But I have [this](http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23u8wh3&s=8#.VTOvjq3tmko) error.

[image]

I run my program used `gcc main.c -cblas` or `gcc main.c`, but the error is same.

I need to add a parameters in gcc compile?

Comment: I don't think you decompile anything, and `ln -s ...` has nothing to do with compilation, I believe you need something like `make -f Makefile.LINUX`, and then `gcc -L/path/to/cblas/binary -lcblas`, `gcc -cblas` is wrong.

Comment: i try but dont' work :/ thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Inline the error message as plain text. And you appear to not be including the CBLAS header.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
1. have you compiled blas and you have the libblas.a? if not, do it.
2. have you update the BLLIB field in Makefile.in to point to your directory. if so you can just go to your directory where the cblas makefile.in is and type make. it should work

Comment: Thanks mates! I solved istalling the library atlas :)